# PHP Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to write a regular expression to validate file names on a file system.

Examples of valid file names are

- tapa_newcougar_org.png
- tapa_lamborghini-talk_com.png
- tapa_clubfrontier_org.png

The logic behind valid is the image starts with tapa followed by an underscore.  Then the domain name followed by _ the tld (com, org, net)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^tapa_[a-z0-9-_]+?_(com|org|net)\.png$/', $string);
```

That ought to do it (tested).  If you want to match capital letters too, add the `i` (case insensitive) flag like this:

```
preg_match('/^tapa_[a-z0-9-_]+?_(com|org|net)\.png$/i', $string);
```

For a graphical representation of how this works, you can paste it in here: http://strfriend.com

Comment: I don't do PHP regex so I don't know what makes it case insensitive (and the OP never specified it should be) but you won't match if the filename has capitals in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
preg_match('/^tapa_.+_(com|org|net)\.png$/', $filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

`^tapa_[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+_(com|org|net)\.png$` should work for you.

Comment: This is too greedy, the .+ will match everything including com|org|net. Also, no file Types?